# Eigenvalues of a matrix with a concentric arrangement of coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix whose coeffiecients can be arranged in the following way
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
        d_1 & d_1 & d_1 & d_1 & \cdots & d_1 \\
        d_1 & d_2 & d_2 & d_2 &\cdots & d_2 \\
        d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_3 & \cdots & d_3 \\
        d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4 & \cdots & d_4 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4 & \cdots & d_n \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Does this class of matrices have a name?
What is the spectrum of this matrix? The spectral radius in the case $0<d_1<d_2<d_3<\dots<d_n$ is for my purposes, but the whole spectrum in the general case would be interesting too.

Comment: Doing Gaussian elimination to get an upper triangular matrix. I.e., an $LU$ decomposition, you'll get diagonal entries of $U$ as $d_1, d_2-d_1, d_3-d_2-d_1, \dots, d_n-d_{n-1}-\cdots-d_1$. Maybe there is a hint here of some diagonalization process?

Comment: This is a semiseparable matrix. One thing that might help you in determining the spectrum is that the inverse of this matrix is tridiagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts.

Your matrix is symmetric, thus has real eigenvalues.

Let

$$H=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0& \dots & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & \dots& 0 \\
\dots &\dots &\dots &\dots &\dots\\
0 &\dots &0&-1 &1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

That is, $H$ is bidiagonal with $1$ on the diagonal and $-1$ on the subdiagonal.

You have $H A H^T = D$, with diagonal $D$.
Also, the diagonal is made of $d_1, d_2-d_1, \dots, d_n-d_{n-1}$.

Thus, $A$ and $D$ are [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence). Then [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia) tells you that there are as many positive (resp. negative, zero) eigenvalues as there are positive (resp. negative, zero) values in the diagonal entries of $D$.
When (and only when) your inequalities hold, that means all eigenvalues are actually positive.

To show the above identity, subtract the row $n-1$ from row $n$, then row $n-2$ from row $n-1$, etc. Then do the same with columns.

This identity also shows that the determinant of $A$ is $d_1(d_2-d_1)\dots(d_n-d_{n-1})$.

---

Also, the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) of $A$ is $d_1+d_2+\dots+d_n$.

This is also the sum of eigenvalues of $A$, but when $d_1 \leq d_2 \leq \dots \leq d_n$, all eigenvalues are nonnegative, and their sum is greater than (or equal to) their maximum.

Therefore, in that case, the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$ is not greater than $d_1+d_2+\dots+d_n$.

This value is only reached when there is only one nonzero eigenvalue, that is when $A$ (and therefore $D$) has [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) one. This can happen only when there is an index $i<n$ and a positive real $t$ such that $d_1=d_2=\dots=d_{i}=0$ and $d_{i+1}=d_{i+2}=\dots=d_n=t$. Then the spectral radius, and only nonzero eigenvalue, is $(n-i)t$. Of course, this does not happen when your inequalities are strict (then all eigenvalues are nonzero).